# C simple algorithm mistake

Tags: c

i\m trying to solve a problem in C where you create a (half)pyramid from the left side and i have done this so far

```
  int height;

do
{
    printf("give the height of the pyramid \n");
    height = GetInt();

}
while(height <= 0  || height > 23 );

for(int i = 2; i < height+2 ; i++)
{
    printf("\n");

    int spacenum = height - i;

    //this is for space
    for(int k = 0; k < spacenum; k++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }


    //this is for  hex
    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }


}
```

getint method is from a custom library its doing like scanf

so if i give an argument lets say 8

it appears like this :

```
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########
#########
```

i want it to look like this :

```
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########
```

what do i have to do ?
something ells is there an anoher better way ? t do something like this with different code ? i mean different method

Comment: What does it look like is wrong with the image? Start from there, and the change should become obvious.

Comment: How about int spacenum = height - i + 1;

Comment: Use `spacenum = height - i + 1`.

Comment: i was adding spaces when i was creating the corrected one and then i realised if i increment the spacenum by one it would work

Comment: "Can't find solution" is not a question. Please [edit] the title to say something meaningful about the problem you're asking us to help you solve. Future readers here searching for a solution to their problem will receive no value from a search result saying "Can't find solution". Please change it to *describe the problem* that your question is about, so people can try to help you. Thanks.

Comment: done, sorry... didnt mean to do that

Comment: I'd hedge money you wouldn't have thought of [**doing this**](http://ideone.com/5AYNgD), but playing with [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) format strings with justifications and fills is always entertaining (and eliminates a nested loop in your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition

```
for(int k = 0; k < spacenum; k++)
```

is causing the problem, it should be

```
for(int k = 0; k <= spacenum; k++)
```

try with

```
int height;

do
{
    printf("give the height of the pyramid \n");
    height = GetInt();

}
while(height <= 0  || height > 23 );

for(int i = 2; i < height+2 ; i++)
{
    printf("\n");

    int spacenum = height - i;

    //this is for space
    for (int k = 0; k <= spacenum; k++) {
    {
        printf(" ");
    }


    //this is for  hex
    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }


}
```

Comment: this is better solution than the above ones it gets rid of the hardcode thank you!

Comment: np, if this is the answer you were looking for the issue, feel free to give me a positive vote on my answer and accept it as the right answer, thx, and good luck with your c learning :)

Comment: i would do that if i had the rep it requires :)